# chainig permission in Django rest framework ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        self.check_object_permissions(request, user)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "list":
            permission_classes = [
                IsAdminUser,
            ]
        elif self.action == "create":
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        else:
            permission_classes = [AccountOwnerPermission | IsAdminUser ]

        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

and custom permission is:

```
class AccountOwnerPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print(object)
        print(request.user)
        return obj == request.user
```

first i dont get object permission but with help of @brian-destura at this question i fixed that part [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70859840/django-rest-framework-custom-permission-for-viewset/70860145#70860145)
now the problem is when i chain 2 permission together it behave like **AllowAny** i check them one by one and both permissions work fine, one of them **allow admin** and one of them **allow owner** but when they are or together it mess everything up

Comment: mess everything up? can you explain what things are messing up

Comment: i put AccountOwnerPermission alone and only account owner can see the view, then i put IsAdminUser alone and only admin can see the view, but when i put AccountOwnerPermission | IsAdminUser everybody can see the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When chaining permissions like

```
permission_classes = [AccountOwnerPermission, IsAdminUser]
```

it behaves like an AND operator between the permission classes

The best option is to create a new permission that allows either the permission logic.

```
class AdminOrAccountOwnerPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj == request.user or request.user.id_admin
```

or this when the permissions used have long complex code to keep code DRY:

```
class AdminOrAccountOwnerPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return AccountOwnerPermission().has_object_permission(request, view, obj) or IsAdminUser().has_object_permission(request, view, obj)
```

EDIT:
Address the question from the comments, the reason why it behaves like `AllowAny`.
`AccountOwnerPermission` has `has_object_permission` but no `has_permission`. On the other hand, `IsAdminUser` has `has_permission` but no `has_object_permission` implemented.

When those functions are not implemented, the functions return `True` by default(from `BasePermission`). As a result, when running `has_permission`, `AccountOwnerPermission` always returns `True` When running `has_object_permission`, `IsAdminUser` is always returning `True`.

Implementing `AccountOwnerPermission.has_permission` would give the expected behavior.

Comment: i though of that too, but i want to know why my permission wont work [AccountOwnerPermission | IsAdminUser ] i even changed permission with or permission and still got bad result, and my view is allowAny i just want to figure out the behavior

Comment: Do you mean that it returns [AllowAny] no matter the case? If so, perhaps using @action decorator and setting the permission classes there could be a way around it.

Comment: @hamzeh_pm, sorry, I got the question now, I edited original answer to answer the AllowAny behavior happening

Comment: thank you @Kyell i get it now, and how it works,thank you for taking time and answer this is exactly what i want to know the base of how it works

Answer (score 1):

@Kyell already described the problem and his answer should be accepted

But I'll try to add some details:

1. When we chain two permission classes DRF creates one new `OR` class:

```py
>>> from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser 
>>> or_class = [IsAdminUser | IsAdminUser]
>>> len(or_class)
1
>>> print(or_class)
[<rest_framework.permissions.OperandHolder object at 0x1096d5fa0>]
>>>
```

2. Django [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) says that `has_object_permission` (check permissions for exact object) method running after `has_permission` (check permissions for whole view class)
3. Let's see how looks these methods inside chained `OR` class:

```py
>>> import inspect
>>> or_instance = or_class[0]()
>>> print(inspect.getsource(or_instance.has_permission))
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return (
            self.op1.has_permission(request, view) or
            self.op2.has_permission(request, view)
        )

>>> print(inspect.getsource(or_instance.has_object_permission))
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return (
            self.op1.has_object_permission(request, view, obj) or
            self.op2.has_object_permission(request, view, obj)
        )
```

So we can see that DRF check both of `has_permission` and after that both of `has_object_permission`

`has_permission` check may be skipped because we run `has_object_permission` after.

But! `has_object_permission` is not implemented inside `IsAdminUser` permission class but it is implemented inside parent `BasePermission` class and looks like:

```py
class BasePermission(metaclass=BasePermissionMetaclass):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return True
```

So `IsAdminUser` always return `True` on `has_object_permission`. In usual cases `IsAdminUser` should fail on `has_permission`, but in your `OR` class `has_permission` passed because it is not implemented inside `AccountOwnerPermission` class

Simplest solution will be to add `has_permission` method to `AccountOwnerPermission` class:

```py
class AccountOwnerPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return False
```

Comment: i get it now, thank you